# Dvorak keyboard layout on stock Android

Tags: keyboard, stock-android

I just updated my Nexus 7 to Jelly-Bean 4.2, and it has the swipe keyboard which is awesome. I want to keep this feature of the stock android keyboard, but with the Dvorak keyboard layout. Is this possible?

I'm NOT looking for a replacement. I like the built in keyboard, I just am wondering if it's possible to change the stock keyboard layout.

Also, if it's easy to switch between Dvorak and qwerty that's preferable :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is supported in stock android.

Settings -> Languages & Input -> Android Keyboard (Settings icon) -> Advanced settings -> Custom input styles -> Add style -> Set Language & Layout

Then to activate this style, go back to the keyboard settings and go to the input languages and uncheck "use system language" then check the languages you want. :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work these days? I don't see "Advanced Settings".

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is possible. Choose the layout from SETTINGS > LANGUAGE AND INPUT and the settings button on the side of the ANdroid keyboard.

You might also try long-pressing the SPACE bar on the keyboard.

[This page](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/) does mention that Jelly Bean has in-built support for DVORAK.

Comment: This worked! I'm trying it now :-) I'll post the steps later :-)

Comment: Too bad that there seems to be support for that one US English Dvorak layout only. 

I'd find other options such as right-hand / left-hand Dvorak or the German or Swedish Dvorak flavors useful and interesting... But they don't seem to exist natively, even with my 7.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Currently,
Settings ->
Language and input ->
Google keyboard ->
Preferences ->
Custom input styles

Select language of choice and Dvorak

Then
Settings ->
Language and input ->
Google keyboard ->
Languages

Turn of system default

Select English(US) Dvorak or similar

Answer (score 0):

Too bad that there seems to be support for that one US English Dvorak layout only.

I'd find other options such as right-hand / left-hand Dvorak or the German or Swedish Dvorak flavors useful and interesting... But they don't seem to exist natively, even with my 7.0 version.